# Getting current location of map on touch in iphone mkmapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

How can I get the location coordinates in mkmapview according to user touching a location on the map on their iphone?

Comment: I want to get coordinates of location when user touches in mkmapview.I mean when user touches on some city then i want to get that location's coordinates. Now am not able to get point in which user touches in mkmapview.

Comment: can you understand my problem in display annotations in mkmapview

Comment: Hope [this][1] article should help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080198/get-the-coordinates-of-a-point-from-mkmapview-on-iphone

Answer (score 3):

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: mapView)
        let location = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        print ("\(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add TapGesture to you mapview and follow below code

```
-(void)didTouchMap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGesure {

         CGPoint touchPoint = [tapGesure locationInView:selectLocationMapView];
         CLLocationCoordinate2D coord= [selectLocationMapView convertPoint:touchPoint      toCoordinateFromView:selectLocationMapView];
         NSLog(@"lat  %f",coord.latitude);
         NSLog(@"long %f",coord.longitude);

}
```