# launch ios map app by clicking on MapView

Tags: ios, swing, mkmapview

I am new to iOS. In my iOS app I am showing a map using MapView.
I am also showing place mark on my map. 
I know how to launch the native app from my app using MKMapItem
But is there a way to launch iOs map app by clicking/touching map?

Answer (score 0):

Add a tap gesture recognizer to the MKMapView, and launch the native maps app based on the lat/long.

Reference:

[Getting current location of map on touch in iphone mkmapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449949/getting-current-location-of-map-on-touch-in-iphone-mkmapview)