# MKpolygon based on tap coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Title says it all. I've been trying create an app that uses a user defined area for a calculation. The user area is going to be created by taking in points that the user taps on a map. I've gotten as far as finding and zooming into the user's location, and switching from normal to satellite, but I cannot figure out how to set points for the polygon.

Basically I need to

1) Get a coordinate (longitude, latitude) from a tap

2) Create a moveable object on that coordinate

3) Use the object's coordinates to create a polygon

Currently I'm stuck on (Get a coordinate from a tap) which is harder than it seems.
If anyone could help or just point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Found this to be very helpful in creating moveable annotations http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/24/swift-mapkit-tutorial-series-how-to-search-a-place-address-or-poi-in-the-map/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Get a coordinate (longitude, latitude) from a tap
      [Get the coordinates of a point from mkmapview on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080198/get-the-coordinates-of-a-point-from-mkmapview-on-iphone)

2) Create a moveable object on that coordinate - Create draggable MKAnnotation

3) Use the object's coordinates to create a polygon - Draw MKPloygon with annotation as center coordinate.